# widehat becomes very big when using mtpro2

Tags: math-mode, equations, symbols, mtpro

I'm using mtpro2 Lite.
When I use widehat it creates a very big widehat as you can see:

[image]

code:

```
\documentclass[article,12pt,oneside]
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \widehat{G(k)}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I downloaded the package from here:
https://ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite?lang=en

Comment: Please post a MWE which actually compiles and reproduces the problem. (`\documentclass[article,12pt,oneside]` should probably be `\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}`, then the `\widehat` works fine)